# Flask-Admin: how to add the database view to a different site

Tags: flask, flask-admin

**Question:** How do I add the flask-admin view (only the table including the possibility to edit/delete entries) to a page outside of flask-admin and the admin route?

I've a page at

```
@app.route("/daten")
@login_required
def ansicht():
     d = current_user.u_daten.order_by('date').all()
     return render_template('ansicht.html',title='Ansicht der Daten', data = d)
```

that renders this template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block app_content %}
<h1>Ansicht der Daten</h1>
<table id="table_id" class="table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
<thead>
  <th> Datum </th>
  <th> Gewicht in Kg</th>
  <th> Körperfett in Prozent</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for element in data %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{ moment(element.date).format('L') }} </td>
    <td align = "right"> {{ element.bw|float}} </td>
    {% set bf = element.bf|float * 100 %}
    <td align = "right"> {{'%0.1f' % bf }}</td>
  </tr>      
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

This works as expected BUT

- I'd like to exchange this table with the flask admin view to include the edit and delete capability.
- I would like to use the navbar from my base.html and not the the menue/navbar from flask-admin

I've built this view to filter only the data from the current user, so that a logged in user can edit his own data.

```
class UserDaten(ModelView):

    can_create = False

    column_exclude_list = ('user_id')
    column_default_sort = ('date', True)
    column_labels = dict(date=u'Datum', bw=u'Körpergewicht in kg', bf=u'Körperfett in Prozent')
    column_formatters = dict(bf=lambda v,c,m,p: m.bf*100, date=lambda v,c,m,p: m.date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))

    form_args = dict(date=dict(label= u'Datum der Messung'  , format='%d.%m.%Y',validators=[DataRequired()]))
    form_excluded_columns = ('user_id')
    form_choices = {'bf': [('0.232','23.2 %'),
                        ('0.218','21.8 %'),
                        ('0.202','20.2 %'),
                        ('0.186','18.6 %'),
                        ('0.168','16.8 %'),
                        ('0.148','14.8 %'),
                        ('0.127','12.7 %'),
                        ('0.105','10.5 %'),
                        ('0.081','8.1 %')]}

    def get_query(self):
        return self.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.user_id == current_user.id)
    def get_count_query(self):
        return self.session.query(func.count('*')).filter(self.model.user_id == current_user.id)

admin.add_view(UserDaten(Daten, db.session))
```

with the

```
admin.add_view(UserDaten(Daten, db.session))
```

I added this view to

```
/admin/daten
```

based on my __init__.py with the line

```
admin = Admin(app)
```

- What I'd like to do now is disable the route /admin and
- include the flask-admin view in the route /daten

I probably have to change the template to include the appropriate jinja tags and add the render function into the class but I can't seem to get it to work.

**TL;DR**
How can I use the "nice" table view from flask-admin and edit/delete functions inside another flask rendered page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine your HTML style with functions provide by Flask-Admin, You can custom the `list.html`, `edit.html` and other template files of Flask-Admin to meet your 
style needs. Use `get_query` to custom the data to show in the table.

To remove the `admin` part of your modelview url, You can set the `url` parameter when you create the instance of Flask-Admin(`admin = Admin(app, "Admin", url='/')`). And set the `endpoint` parameter when you add modelview to admin(`admin.add_view(UserDaten(User, db.session, endpoint='daten'))`).

Comment: thank you for your answer, after many trials I was able to rediirect the base template and now have a table which includes the flask admin ability